# traffic routing with DNS

Tags: iptables, iproute

I have 2 gateway machines. 1 debian (main - 192.168.1.1), 1 centos (backup 192.168.1.2).
There are 2 networks, 1 LAN and 1 WAN, going through "main" and from there over ISP1
"backup" is on LAN and it goes out to ISP2 via PPP (basically over 3G stick)

The problem is, when ISP1 is "dead" or dropping packets due to bad weather or whatever, I want to be able to manually set **certain** stations from LAN to have their INTERNET traffic over ISP2, leaving the rest on ISP1.
So let's assume that I want 192.168.1.3 to normally have internet over GW1/ISP1, and then at some point I want to manually switch it to GW2/ISP2.
I need to do this without "touching" stations network settings, as much as possible because it will bust up local network connections, which *mustn't* happen.

192.168.1.3 (WinXP) has default gateway 192.168.1.1 and DNS server set up by DHCP means to the 2 DNS servers of ISP1

I tried various solutions with DNAT (which seemed to replace any external IP with 192.168.1.2 and hence communication stopped there) and ip route (which messed up local network communications)

I think I'm not seeing something obvious in the iptables DNAT solution but I cannot put my finger on it.
for reference, the line looks liek this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.3 ! -d 192.168.1.0/8 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2
```

the ip rout was done like this:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.3 via 192.168.1.2
```

Both done on GW1 (192.168.1.1)

ip forward is enabled in GW2 (obviously everything works fine in terms of routing and NATing in GW1 - by itself)

iptables rules on GW2 look like this (from iptables-save) cause I'm not really sure it's fine.

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21038:1379326]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [302:19015]
-A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [61306:4073979]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [27660:3745654]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.3/32 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.3/32 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I forgot to answer back. So this is how I eventually solved it:

- I setup LAN1 to also host a forwarding DNS server
- I changed my DHCP settings and changed the DNS server from the ISP one, to the local once (LAN1)
- I wrote a script on the 3g router that gets network info, configures itself as local gateway, changes the LAN gateway to point to itself and which basically looks like this (must be executed right after the 3g connection via vwdial is made (I have a different script for that since I like to keep that up to watch successful connection and any network issues)):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# get info
LOCAL_IP=`tail -n 20 /var/log/messages | grep pppd | grep local | sed "s/.*IP address \(.*\)/\1/"`
REMOTE_IP=`tail -n 20 /var/log/messages | grep pppd | grep ": remote" | sed "s/.*IP address \(.*\)/\1/"`
DNS1=`tail -n 20 /var/log/messages | grep pppd | grep ": primary" | sed "s/.*DNS address \(.*\)/\1/"`
DNS2=`tail -n 20 /var/log/messages | grep pppd | grep ": secondary" | sed "s/.*DNS address \(.*\)/\1/"`
echo got info LOCAL_IP=$LOCAL_IP REMOTE_IP=$REMOTE_IP DNS1=$DNS1 DNS2=$DNS2

# setup self as gateway
echo nameserver $DNS1>/etc/resolv.conf
echo nameserver $DNS2>>/etc/resolv.conf
route del default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
route add default gw $REMOTE_IP ppp0
echo done setting up self with new params

# setup old gateway to forward to self
echo changing dplug routes
ssh root@192.168.1.1 'route del default gw X.Y.Z.W eth0'
ssh root@192.168.1.1 'route add default gw 192.168.1.7 eth1'
echo removing dplug LAN SNAT
ssh root@192.168.1.1 'iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source A.B.C.D'
echo deleting WIFI SNAT
ssh root@192.168.1.1 'eval "$(cat firewall/iptables | grep "\-A POSTR" | grep -v "\#" | sed "s/-A/iptables -t nat -D/")"'
echo adding new WIFI SNAT
ssh root@192.168.1.1 'eval "$(cat firewall/iptables | grep "\-A POSTR" | grep -v "\#" | grep 192.168.2 | sed "s/\(-A .*\) -o .*/iptables -t nat \1 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1/")"'
echo setting up dnsmasq DHCP for new values
ssh root@192.168.1.1 'echo "# this dnsmasq config file is generated by 3g router. do not edit.">/etc/dnsmasq.3g.conf'
ssh root@192.168.1.1 "echo server=$DNS1>>/etc/dnsmasq.3g.conf"
ssh root@192.168.1.1 "echo server=$DNS2>>/etc/dnsmasq.3g.conf"
ssh root@192.168.1.1 "echo dhcp-option=net:wlan,6,$DNS1,$DNS2>>/etc/dnsmasq.3g.conf"
ssh root@192.168.1.1 "echo dhcp-option=net:lan,6,$DNS1,$DNS2>>/etc/dnsmasq.3g.conf"
echo restarting dnsmasq
ssh root@192.168.1.1 '/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart'
echo all done
```

/etc/dnsmasq.3g.conf is included in the dnsmasq.conf and it is originally empty.
There is a script to undo the above in a minimalistic manner since I then just kill the 3g router VM (unplugging the 3g usb stick results in kernel panic...), so I don't really care about it.

The script makes sure that only those WAN IPs that are configured for internet access will continue to have internet access, and none other.
The LAN IP's for internet access are manually added to the 3g router's iptables. (those don't change)

Answer (score 1):

Your Debian router (main — 192.168.1.1) should not be attempting to NAT traffic in order to redirect it to the backup router. At best, this will result in double NAT (since the backup router will NAT it again in the way out of `ppp0` as per its `MASQUERADE` rule) and at worst you will rewrite the IP addresses in a way that makes it impossible for the return traffic to get back.

The simplest option is to use VRRP. Setup a virtual gateway address shared between both routers. Set the priorities so that the main router takes the master role by default but steps down when its own Internet connection is not available. Under Linux, use [vrrpd](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/net/vrrpd) to implement VRRP. Then set the default gateway of those workstations you want to switch to the virtual gateway address, while leavign the rest pointed to the main router's real IP address.

If you want to do this really manually, you don't even need VRRP. Just manage the virtual gateway address manually by removing it from the main router (`ip addr del x.y.z.w/qq dev eth?`) and adding it to the other one (`ip addr add x.y.z.w/qq dev eth?`). Note however that true VRRP manages MAC addresses in addition to IP addresses so you may experience some ARP problems if you go the manual route (no pun intended).

Another approach is to install a static default route on the Debian router that points toward the backup router. You can use policy routing (with `ip rule`) to apply this route only to packets with certain source IP addresses. This route should have a higher metric than the default route that goes out the WAN. Thus, when the default route out the WAN is present, it gets used exclusively, and otherwise traffic follows the fallback default route. This kind of default route may or may not result in ICMP redirects being sent to workstations. You might want to disable those so that workstations promptly return to the main route when it comes back, assuming the main router can handle the in & back out traffic that it redirects to the other router. (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/<intf>/send_redirects`)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I feel that both your suggested methods will apply to all stations on the LAN, whereas I only want some of them (decided at the moment I need it) to route/redirect to ISP2. I've updated the question to make that more clear. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I did miss your requirement to change routing only for **certain** workstations. I have revised my answer, including reversing the order of preference of the two solutions.

Comment: I also did specify that local LAN connections must not be reset. At least on WinXP, changing the default gateway kills all LAN connections.

Comment: On a side note, I've set up another CentOS box, and configured it for NAT over GW2. That works fine. I then changed it's default gateway to GW1 (left DNS for ISP2) and attempted route definitions on GW1 so that packets go to GW2. I went with "ip route add 192.168.1.3 via 192.168.1.2" but it doesn't seem to work. Issued a ping -c 1 92.87.232.114 resulting in http://pastebin.com/sjp8mBfa and no trace on GW2. NOTE: eth1 is LAN, eth0 is ISP1